# How to detect if the app was minimized IOS

Tags: ios

I'm fairly new to ios development. I'm actually coming from Flutter and have to make these native calls myself.

Basically, my app runs a timer/countdown (5-10mins). If the user minimises the app I want to stop the timer (e.g. user starts doing something else with the phone). If the user, however, simply locks their screen, I want the timer to continue.

I tried using some of the lifecycle calls like `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillTerminate`, however, it seems both are called for minimization and screen off. How do I do it?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-detect-when-your-app-moves-to-the-background

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for? The AppDelegate lifecycle things are the way to go anyway.

Comment: @OscarApeland yes, so I tried `applicationWillResignActive` but it fires for both minimizing the app and locking the phone/screen off. I need to be able to distinguish between them in my case.